# Improving outputs in tikz package

Tags: latex, tikz

```latex
$F_1(g)=\left\{ 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[shape=circle,draw=black] (A) {$b^1_0$}; 
\end{tikzpicture} \right\}$
```

Doing this code, I have an output like this [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4gDD.png)

And I'd like something more centered into the brackets, like if I'm still writing instead of drawing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change the baseline of the picture to be at its center, then align that baseline to the vertical center of the text. This can be done with the option `[baseline={([yshift=-.8ex]current bounding box.center)}]`. I added it to the example code you gave, and also changed the `inner sep` of the `circle` to 0pt. Let me know if that works for you.

```latex
$F_1(g)=\left\{ 
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={([yshift=-.8ex]current bounding box.center)}]
\node[shape=circle,draw=black, inner sep=0pt] (A) {$b^1_0$}; 
\end{tikzpicture} \right\}$

\end{document}
```